# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uniqueness"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, client-side-validation

I am getting an error on uniqueness , I am using [client side validation](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) gem

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uniqueness"):
```

Here are the versions which i am using

```
client_side_validations (3.2.5)
client_side_validations-formtastic (2.2.1)
client_side_validations-simple_form (2.0.0)
simple_form (2.1.0, 2.0.4, 2.0.0, 1.5.2)
```

I have found this [issue on github](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/113), It says to use the updated versions of the gem which i am already using. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.The form is created with simple form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved this issue by making changes in the rails.validations.js

First i have generated the js via

```
rails g client_side_validations:copy_assets
```

On line 550

changed

```
return "//" + window.location.host + "//" + ClientSideValidations.remote_validators_prefix + "/validators/" + validator;
```

to

```
return "//" + window.location.host + ClientSideValidations.remote_validators_prefix + "/validators/" + validator;
```

Did this because the ajax request was something like this

```
http://localhost:3000//validators/uniqueness?case_sensitive=false&user%5Blogin%5D=john&_=1365516039852
```

You can notice there is two slashes

```
http://localhost:3000//
```

Comment: note this only happens with localhost and not in production.  I don't think the gem has fixed it for dev env.

Comment: I issued [a pull request](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/pull/532), that fixes the problem based on your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it was suggested in https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/pull/532#issuecomment-17316312 I added the following line:

```js
ClientSideValidations.remote_validators_prefix = null;
```